# Why is the Conductivity trend same in fused and in dissolved or aqueous state of ionic compounds?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility, ionic-compounds

For an example if we take $\ce{KCl}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$ then I have understood the part where in aqueous state $\ce{Na+}$ becomes bigger than $\ce{K+}$ hence the conductivity reverses but in fused state ions exist on their own hence the conductivity order must remain $\ce{Na+} \gt \ce{K+}$

Comment: Consider proper capitalization of chemical element symbols to be taken seriously. k is the Boltzmann constant.

Comment: "Naked" $\ce{Na+}$ ions in melted salt, being smaller and more polarizing, may have bigger tendency to form ionic pairs with $\ce{Cl-}$, similarly as $\ce{Mg^2+(aq)}$ and SO4^2-(aq) have tendency to form ionic pairs is sea water as $\ce{MgSO4(aq)}$

Comment: So basically in fused state as they are not solvated the ions having more effective nuclear charge(polarizing power) are able to interact more effectively with each other for an instance say Na+ and Cl- hence they reduce each others movement??

Comment: Ionic pairs do not electromigrate.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that ?

Comment: Does Na+Cl- pair migrate to the cathode or the anode ?

Comment: As per my knowledge they move individually Na+ to cathode and Cl- to anode

Comment: While they form a bound ion pair, then no, they do not, similsrly as ion pair MgSO4(aq) is sea water. There is formation equilibrium and the ion pair fraction causes effective ion mobility slowing down.

Comment: Thank You now I think I have understood